# What causes the exit status to change for the same command even when the output is identical?

Tags: shell, ksh, exit-code

In the below code, I am trying to check if the command within the `if` condition completed successfully and that the data was pushed into the target file temp.txt.

**Consider:**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

A=4
B=1

$(tail -n $(( $A - $B )) sample.txt > temp.txt)
echo "1. Exit status:"$?

if [[ $( tail -n $(( $A - $B )) sample.txt > temp.txt ) ]]; then
    echo "2. Exit status:"$?
    echo "Command completed successfully"
else
    echo "3. Exit status:"$?
    echo "Command was unsuccessfully"
fi
```

**Output:**

```
$ sh sample.sh
1. Exit status:0
3. Exit status:1
```

Now I can't get why the exit status changes above.. when the output of both the instances of the tail commands are identical. Where am I going wrong here..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you're getting the exit status of a call to the `tail` command (the [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#SUBSHELLSREF) you spawned with `$()` preserves the last exit status)

In the second case, you're getting the exit status of a call to the `[[ ]]` Bash built-in. But this is actually testing the **output** of your `tail` command, which is a completely different operation. And since that output is **empty**, the test fails.

Consider :

```
$ [[ "" ]]           # Testing an empty string
$ echo $?            # exit status 1, because empty strings are considered equivalent to FALSE
1
$ echo               # Empty output

$ echo $?            # exit status 0, the echo command executed without errors
0
$ [[ $(echo) ]]      # Testing the output of the echo command
$ echo $?            # exit status 1, just like the first example.
1
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo $?            # No errors here either
0
$ [[ $(echo foo) ]]
$ echo $?            # Exit status 0, but this is **NOT** the exit status of the echo command.
0
```

Comment: Hi Miklos, thanks! But why does it return `1`(Error?) in the 2nd case when there isn't any error in the command's execution..?